# Setting up Active directory on Azure as a failover instance

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, adfs

We want to setup our enterprise Active Directory on Azure as a fail-over option. ie If the on-premise AD goes down, we should be able to seamlessly switch over to Azure for authentication. How do we realize this?

1. Should I be considering Windows Azure Active directory (WAAD) or
           setup a domain controller on an Azure VM image?
2. In both the cases, how do we setup a sync to ensure both on-premise
   and Azure AD are always in sync?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think that the Windows Azure Active Directory cannot be used for Enterprise login. It can be synced with On-Premises AD to provide SSO funcionalities across applications, but not to provide Windows Kerberos Authentication.

Installing an AD in a Windows Azure VM would be the way to go here. And the way you do is by [creating a Replica AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-install-replica-active-directory-domain-controller/) having your primary AD on premises and your secondary in the Azure VM. You have [create a Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal/) and add it to your local net, so that the Azure VM is accessible from the local net.

A good-to-know is also how the [Windows Azure Name Resolution](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/) works.

Comment: You're correct, Azure AD is entirely different, and would not achieve the goal.